# Why can't i resize my image?

Tags: modeling

I am following a tutorial on youtube and when the instructor wants to resize his photo he can find a box that says "size". But when I am trying to find it just not there. Where is the box???!?!?!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Found it, my bad!

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, I had to make the Properties panel larger (opened by pressing <kbd>N</kbd> 3D viewport).

[image]